# FaceBook Like Share Counter Issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have one web page which has Facebook like and share button with separate code. But when I click on like button it also increase the counter of share button and when i click on share button it increases the counter of like button but I want to keep it separate.

Code:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" style="float:right; margin:0 0 0 5px;" data-href="pageurl?nid=120" data-type="button_count"></div>
<div class="fb-like" style="float:right; margin:0 0 0 5px;" data-href="pageurl?nid=120" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
```

So if you have any solution on this then please share it with me.

Comment: It's a normal behavior since the `data-href` attribute value is the same `URL`

Answer (score 0):

It was expected behaviour, because the number to show is the total of shares + likes + comments.

For example, the page at http://ent.sinchew.com.my/node/47354 show **737** on Like button.

[image]

You can get the total of each likes/comments/shares with FQL via link_stat table, e.g.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20click_count%2C%20comment_count%2C%20like_count%2C%20share_count%2C%20total_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%20%3D%20'www.google.com'

[image]

As you can see, 27 + 672 + 38 = 737, in which 737 is the total you see on Like button. Even you put Share button instead of Like button, the total is same, i.e. 737